# Format text using VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am fairly new so please excuse my ignorance..
I want to format bookmark (Rich Text Content Control).

I have the following code to do that

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ALTERNATIVE").Range.Font.TextColor = back
more formatting to text
```

My question is how can I do that efficiently? Is there a way to select multiple bookmarks or select all Rich Text Content Control to do the format on all of them in the same code?

Comment: Are you looking for code to loop through all the bookmarks or content controls to apply the formatting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs you could use either approach:

1. Loop through the Content controls to update the formatting:

   ```
   For Each oContentControl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
       oContentControl.Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
   Next
   ```
2. Loop through all the bookmarks to achieve the same result:

   ```
   For Each bookmark In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
       bookmark.Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
   Next
   ```

**EDIT**

As per request, below is how to fine tune the above loop for content controls of a certain type ([MSDN Link for types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197873.aspx)).

1.a Loop through all richText content controls to update the formatting:

```
For Each oContentControl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If oContentControl .Type = wdContentControlRichText Then
        oContentControl.Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
    End If
Next
```

Comment: can the first code be written so only Rich Text content control get affected?

Comment: Sure, code updated to reflect searching for content controls of type `wdContentControlRichText`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this might do?

```
Dim Bmk As Bookmark

For Each Bmk In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    Debug.Print Bmk.Range.Font.TextColor
Next Bmk
```

Comment: @1990Mustafa yes, within your loop you can check the bookmark being worked on and skip it (Something like `If Bmk.Name = "ALTERNATIVE"`